# Adding code to the WndProc callback in WNDCLASSEX breaks code

Tags: c++, user-interface, system

I have this code which is part of my user interface system that I am creating that will have multiple windows

```
bool UISystem::HandleMessage(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UIWindow* target = NULL;
    for(vector<UIWindow*>::iterator it = windowList.begin(); it < windowList.end(); it++)
    {
        if((*it)->windowHandle == hwnd)
        {
            target = *it;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(target == NULL)
    { return false; }

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:

        return true;

    case WM_PAINT:  

        return true;

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

LRESULT WINAPI UISystem::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    /*if(UISYSTEM->HandleMessage(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam))
    {
    }*/
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When this code is implemented as it is, including the comment block in UISystem::WndProc, a window is displayed correctly however, if I uncomment this block in UISystem::WndProc then an invalid handle is returned from CreateWindow any help would be appreciated because this is really confusing me, I have tried to call DefWindowProc before I do any other code in UISystem::WndProc but all my attemps have failed

This is the Constructor for UIWindow:

```
UIWindow::UIWindow(int x, int y, int width, int height, string & text)
{

    int frameWidth   = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
    int frameHeight  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
    int menuHeight   = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);
    int windowXPos   = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - width) / 2;
    int windowYPos   = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - height) / 2;
    int windowWidth  = width + frameWidth * 2;
    int windowHeight = height + frameHeight * 2 + menuHeight;

    bounds.X = x;
    bounds.Y = y;
    bounds.Width = width;
    bounds.Height = height;
    title = text;

    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_VREDRAW|CS_HREDRAW|CS_OWNDC, 
        &UISystem::WndProc, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL, NULL, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1), 
        NULL, "AurousWindow", NULL};

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);


    windowHandle = CreateWindow("AurousWindow", title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, windowXPos, windowYPos, windowWidth, windowHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowRgn(windowHandle, CreateRectRgn(0, 0, width, height), TRUE);
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, nShow);
    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);

    //RECT rec = {0, 0, width, height};

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, instead of maintaining a global list of all windows, you can store user data in the window by calling SetWindowLong with GWL_USERDATA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the root problem but one thing you should fix is to remove:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

from:

```
UIWindow::UIWindow(int x, int y, int width, int height, string & text)
```

this while will loop as long as your window exists and will prevent UIWindow from being properly constructed. This object (UIWindow) is actually being accessed inside: UISystem::HandleMessage, but since its constructor never ends then it is probably NULL or in undefined state.

Comment: luskan, how can I then keep the message pump going for each window without the whole application closing?

Comment: Look in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, you should have one message loop per thread, just put it in you main() function and it will be ok. Initializations do before this loop.

Comment: I think I may have accidently deleted your comment luskan, Sorry!

How does this look? http://pastebin.com/K9sFnJ3E

Comment: you want to have a separate thread for each window (also look at CWinThread)? If so you must create each window in its own thread. But all UIs are not being build that way, mostly you have one GUI thread where all windows are being created.

Comment: My method didn't work and I put the message loop in the main entry point, still to no avail :(

Comment: another problem (or rather the same as in my answer) is that CreateWindow() will fire first messages (WM_CREATE) which will be handled by UISystem::HandleMessage, but since CreateWindow is inside constructor then its still wrong. You should remove all that code from constructor to some other method.

Comment: Understandable, I have now moved the structure of the code so that the window is created and the WndProc is called before being added to the windowList but still to no avail...

Comment: sorry, thats all I could help - you should start with something small and working and then do more complicated stuff